Can't generate signed APK for release Android Studio
At first i generated an apk normally using a key store i created, it worked but when i made some changes to a layout and an activity and tried generating an apk again, an error inside a generated build file of the modified layout interrupts the build process, the file is named after the layout which is like this "LayoutNameBinding.java"
Heres a screenshot of the error source
error source
Heres the output of the build
build output

deleted the previous APK files from the release folder
created a new key store
changed the output directory of the APK


Please don't post error messages as screenshot. The error message ist just colored text, copy it to clipboard and paste it into your question, then format it as code.

"...it worked but when i made some changes to a layout..." There could be a mistake in the layout XML file.

Looks like this issue is related to this post.
Try the following:

Clean project
Rebuild project
Invalidate caches and restart

Hopefully, this should solve the issue.

Awesome, well done!
